# React Router intercepting API call to Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, react-router, passport.js

I'm using React Router with Passport.js to set up Facebook login. I've set up the express routes and passport config, but every time I hit the 
`<a href="/api/auth/facebook">` link on my client side, it makes a request to RR because of my express app with this line:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client', 'build', 'index.html'))
});
```

As I am making a call to the server side route, it returns this error:

```
Warning: [react-router] Location "/api/auth/facebook" did not match any routes
```

How can I bypass React Router for this one particular route?

my user_routes.js file looks like:

```
'user strict';

var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var User = require('../models/User.js');

module.exports = function loadUserRoutes(router, passport) {
  router.use(bodyparser.json());

  router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    session: false,
    successRedirect: '/chat',
    failureRedirect: '/'
  }));

  router.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    session: false,
    successRedirect: '/chat',
    failureRedirect: '/'
  }));

  router.post('/sign_up', passport.authenticate('local-signup', { session: false}), function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.user);
  });

  router.post('/sign_in', passport.authenticate('local-login', { session: false}), function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.user);
  });

  router.get('/signout', function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.end();
  });

  //get auth credentials from server
  router.get('/load_auth_into_state', function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.user);
  });

  // get usernames for validating whether a username is available
  router.get('/all_usernames', function(req, res) {
    User.find({'local.username': { $exists: true } }, {'local.username': 1, _id:0}, function(err, data) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({msg: 'internal server error'});
      }
      res.json(data);
    });
  })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In express routes are matches in the order they get defined.

So before your `/*` route you need something to handle api requests.

```
app.get('/api/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'))

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client', 'build', 'index.html'))
});
```

Comment: I currently have:
require('./routes/user_routes')(usersRouter, passport);
app.use('/api', usersRouter);

Comment: Tried this line and the console is still returning the same error message.

Comment: From the limited amount I can see. `app.use('/api', usersRouter);` isn't doing what you think it is doing. Can you get to `/api/auth/facebook` just by going to it in your browser? My suspicion is the route is _actually_ `/auth/facebook` and so the catch all is getting it.